# Does JOOQ Support SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008 R2 in Code Generator?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, jooq

I've been trying to auto-generate artefacts for my SQL Server Database. Its originally from SQL Server 2005, and then I didnt find in the documentation of JOOQ, so i imported it on a 2008 R2. But then its still says the same thing:

`1428 [main] WARN org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase  - No schemata were loaded  : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ. Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : [box_db]`

Can some JOOQ expert point me to the right direction on where I can see supported JOOQ Database, or just answer it directly.

Here's the result of trying the JOOQ Generator without input in `withInputSchemata`:

```
schema_name
---------------------
dbo
guest
INFORMATION_SCHEMA
sys
db_owner
db_accessadmin
db_securityadmin
db_ddladmin
db_backupoperator
db_datareader
db_datawriter
db_denydatareader
db_denydatawriter`
```

Comment: The lowest SQL Server version that is supported by jOOQ 3.x is SQL Server 2008 R2. [The official info can be found here](http://www.jooq.org/legal/licensing#databases). Can you show the exact error message (e.g. stack trace) that you're getting when you're running the import with 2008 R2? I know you said it was hard to get those messages, but without them, it'll be also hard to help...

Comment: Hello @LukasEder, appreciate your reply. I now got a hold of my internet. So here's my code. [link]http://pastebin.com/ku9an3Lb[link]. and the error messge is: `1428 [main] WARN org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase  - No schemata were loaded  : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ. Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : [box_db]`.

Comment: @LukasEder I'm also curious to know how the pro-edition would expire when used? I just use a SQLExpress and would just like to use it for generating artefacts for a thirdparty database.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. I think I know what's going on now. Could you also add the results of the following query to your question? `SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata`. Is `box_db` (in lower case) part of the result? What happens if you leave `withInputSchema` empty in your configuration? About the licensing question, I believe that is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and not appreciated by the moderators. However, I will be more than happy to answer if there's any way I can contact you.

Comment: Hello, here's the result: [link](http://pastebin.com/xX2qZCCb) result. and its not part of the results. You can contact me via facebook joeffrey.biccay[@]gmail[dot]com.

Comment: Leaving `withInputSchemata` created a bunch of unneeded artefacts. at least in my POV. They are for the entries that you saw in the pastebin link.

Comment: Thanks for the additional feedback. Sure, the "unneeded artefacts" don't need to be generated. I was just curious to see if leaving out the schema name would produce the missing schema (and others) for you. I think there's enough information in the question now for an answer, which I've given. About the licensing, I'll reach out to you via E-Mail, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to your question lies in the error message from the code generator. The list of schemas that you've displayed has been produced by the following query

```sql
SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata
```

This query is also used by the code generator when reverse-engineering your database schema. It doesn't contain any schema called `box_db`.

There are several reasons why this might be the case:

- You are confusing the "database" with the "schema". jOOQ's code generator only filters for the schema.
- You're not connecting to the right database
- Your database might not contain the schema
- The user you're connecting to the database with doesn't have the required privileges to access that schema

Comment: 1. box_db is the database that I am trying to connect
2. box_db sure does show up on my object explorer. I am not sure If on my import of the database, the schema is also included. (just until your answer, i only thought DB and schema were the same thing)
3. `sa` user is the main user configured on installation I used.

Comment: But is `box_db` the database (which corresponds to the "catalog") or the schema? jOOQ currently only introspects the schema. Perhaps, your tables are located in the `dbo` schema?

Comment: Correct. I figured last night researching about schemas and saw dbo as the prefix of my tables. I never tried to change it and started generating the artefacts right away. Thanks Lukas!